# Remove part of value of option in select

Tags: jquery

I have a `select` with multiple `options` for the archives of my WordPress site.

The `select` looks like this:

```
<select name="m" onchange="this.form.submit()" title="Archive">
    <?php $archives = wp_get_archives( array( 'format' => 'option' ) ); ?>
    <?php echo $archives ;?>
</select>
```

That generates a select that looks like this:

```
<select name="m" onchange="this.form.submit()" title="Archive">
    <option value="http://site_name/?m=201503">march 2015</option>
    <option value="http://site_name/?m=201501">january 2015</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to remove the `http://site_name/?m=` part from the `value` attribute in the `option`.

I think jQuery is the best option here, but I have no clue where to start with jQuery.

Comment: when u need to remove on load ? or on change @Liam de Hass

Comment: Yes I need to remove on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dom ready you can remove it like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('select[name="m"] option').attr('value', function (i, v) {
        return v.match(/\d+$/)[0]
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v3t1hqvu/)

Comment: And what would it look like if the url looks like this: `http://site_name/2015/03/` and I want to keep `201503`?

Comment: try `return v.match(/\d+/g).join('')`

Answer (score 0):

use this on doc ready:

```js
    $('select[title="Archive"]').find('option').each(function() {
      var newVal = this.value.split('=')[1];
      this.value = newVal;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="m" onchange="this.form.submit()" title="Archive">
  <option value="http://site_name/?m=201503">march 2015</option>
  <option value="http://site_name/?m=201501">january 2015</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/x7k900sz/)

```
 $('option').each(function(i,ele){
        var x=$(ele).val();
        $(ele).val(x.replace("http://site_name/?m=", ""));
    });
```

put the code in document ready function

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dg1tysyt/1/)

```
$('select option').each(function(i,element){
        var optvalue=$(element).val();
        var result = optvalue.replace("http://site_name/?m=", "");
    console.log(result);
      $(element).val(optvalue.replace("http://site_name/?m=", ""));
    });
```